# Apache Ranger REST API startIndex request param is ignoring

Tags: rest, httprequest, apache-ranger

Apache Ranger v 2.1.0.
I try send get request
"/service/public/v2/api/policy/?pageSize=10&startIndex=15"
or
"/service/public/v2/api/policy?pageSize=10&startIndex=15"
or
"/service/public/v2/api/service/hadoop/policy?pageSize=10&startIndex=15"
to REST API Ranger but always see 10 results from 1 record (49 policies).
Why startIndex request param is ignoring?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I haven't used this software.

Try without the trailing slash, i.e. like so:

```
/service/public/v2/api/policy?pageSize=10&startIndex=15
```

Also, according to the documentation, the syntax is like so:

```
/service/public/v2/api/service/{service-name}/policy
```

Notice the {service-name} in there. I don't see this in your example.

Comment: In both variants the startIndex is ignoring.

Comment: Update your starting post with the new data and the url's you tried. Maybe someone else has any idea then.